# Compare Two Movies from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help I feel like I'm on the right track but don't know what to do next.

Heres what i have so far:

```
def compareTwoMovies(movie1, movie2):

    file = open("actors.txt", "r")

    lines = file.readlines()

    movies = {}

    actors = set()


    for lines in file:
        actorList = lines.split(",")
        movieTitle = actorList[0]
        movieActors = actorList[1:]

        for movie in file:

            if movie not in movies:
                movies = movies[movie]
                actors.add(movie)

            else:
                actors.add(movie)
```

Read in the lines from the "actors.txt" file.
For each line:
   Separate out the movie and the actors.
   For each movie listed:

a) If the movie name has not already been entered into the dictionary,
    add it as a key, and store the SET of the actor as a value.

b) If the movie name exists in the dictionary, add the actors name to 
         the set of actors .i.e. to the value in the dictionary.

The dictionary is now ready.
Process the input to the function.

Are both of the inputs keys in your dictionary?

a)  If not, then print an appropriate error message and quit.

b)  If so, perform the three "searches" and print their results.

Comment: Is your "actors.txt" file set out like so: movie,actor,actor1 <newline> movie1,actor1,actor2 etc?

Answer (score 0):

Some issues I can see.

movies = movies[movie] removes the old value of movies. You're looking for something like movies[movieTitle] = actors.

actors = set() needs to happen for each line.

There is no need for `for movie in file`. Processing each line twice in the file will cause strange issues.

`if movie not in movies` should use the movieTitle `if movieTitle not in movies`

You need to step through each actor in movieActors.

Answer (score 0):

```
def compareTwoMovies(movie1, movie2):

    file = open("actors.txt", "r")

    lines = file.readlines()# not needed

    movies = {}

    actors = set()


    for lines in file:
        actorList = lines.split(",")
        movieTitle = actorList[0]
        movieActors = actorList[1:]

        for movie in file:

            if movie not in movies:
                movies = movies[movie]
                actors.add(movie)

            else:
                actors.add(movie)
        #what is the necessity of two for loop? why not only one?
```

the code I propose is as follows

```
def Init_movies_tree(tree_file_name):   
    file = open(tree_file_name, 'r')
    movies = {}
    actors = set()        
    for line in file:
        actorList = line.split(",")
        movieTitle = actorList[0]
        movieActors = actorList[1:]
        movies.setdefault(movieTitle, movieActors)
        actors.add(movieTitle)
    return movies


def compareTwoMovies1(movie1, movie2, tree, debug=False):
    if debug:
       print('Movie[1] name:%s, actors:%s\n'%(movie1, tree[movie1]))
       print('Movie[2] name:%s, actors:%s\n'%(movie2, tree[movie2]))
       #print(f'Movie[1] name:{movie1}, actors:{tree[movie1]})
       #print(f'Movie[2] name:{movie2}, actors:{tree[movie2]})
    if (movie1 == movies2) and movie1 in tree:
       return True
    return False


Tree = Init_movies_tree("actors.txt")
v = compareTwoMovies(movie1, movie2, Tree)
print(v)
```